# Visual Basic for Applications Object Issue

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is part of a much larger Sub for a form automation project I've been working on for my employer.

```
'the following variable is named thusly for good reason.
Dim whyareyouactinglikethis As Object
Set whyareyouactinglikethis = Workbooks("DRQ Log.xlsx").Worksheets("DRQ's")
Dim finalRow As Object
With whyareyouactinglikethis
    Set finalRow = Cells(99999, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Dim Source As Range
Source = whyareyouactinglikethis.Range("D8:D" & finalRow & "")
```

So my current issue is that for whatever reason, I get a run time error 424 when I set finalRow. I'm really confused as to why this is as "whyareyouactinglikethis" is clearly set to an Object that the with statement is using, and so is finalRow. I've been staring at this multiple ways for the last two hours, here's what I've tried.

Changing finalRow to a long variable

Changing finalRow to a Range variable (This introduces an error 91 statement)

Activating and selecting whyareyouactinglikethis before setting finalRow so I know this isn't some .select error or lack of proper references.

What do I need to do to fix this? Please let me know. I'm still somewhat new to Visual Basic, so I'm unsure if it's just my inexperience or if this is a legitimate issue.

Comment: Remove the `Set` and make `finalRow` a `Long`. You are also missing a `Set`: `Set Source = ...`

Comment: There is no reason to use `Object` variables either: `Dim whyareyouactinglikethis as Worksheet`.

Comment: And you're missing a period: `finalRow = .Cells(....)`... and instead of that hard-coded `99999`, use `.Rows.Count`.

Comment: @BigBen thank you so much that fixed most of my issues,

Answer (score 0):

You `Set` objects (*Workbooks, Sheets, Ranges, etc.*) and assign values (*last row variables, strings, etc*).

---

```
Sub try()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DRQ's")
Dim lr As Long, Source As Range

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Source = ws.Range("D8:D" & lr)

End Sub
```

---

*Also, a more piratical last row calc is used here rather arbitrarily starting from row 99,999*

Comment: More piratical... ay ay matey!